# Custom input fields Wordpress back-end

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I am working on a food-blog theme for Wordpress and I want the admin user to be able to add recipies in the back-end.
I'm thinking of a custom post format section similar to the regular post section where the user can add a title, the post itself, an excerpt etc. 
I know how I can make such a section, but I want a custom field/row where the user adds an ingredient such as "water" and can add an amount and adds "grams"/"kilograms" etc. And do this for every ingredient.

I hope someone can help me with this, thanks!

Comment: You can use advanced custom fields plugin for this

Comment: Use [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields) Plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Advanced custom fields 
Documentation below
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-field-group/

You can create fields that a user can insert data into and then you just parse that data into the the single page.

It is all documented nicely on the link above.